# Si no tengo informacion en el resultado, ponerme 0 oracle

Tags: php, oracle

Tengo el siguiente query en **Oracle SQL** que me devuelve como resultado "no existe" o "Black" por asi decirlo, ya que lo filtro por un ID y dicho ID no existe que me ponga un 0.

en el Ejemplo siguiente se muesta la cantidad que tengo segun el ID que mando a llamar pero si tengo un ID que no tiene datos no me trai nada(No me lo trai en la lista)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en esa consulta mande a llamar AI pero como no tiene datos no lo muestra y me gustaria ponerle un "0"
para que me nuestre toda la lista que mando a llamar.

Esta es la consulta que estoy realizando.

**Consulta**

```
    SELECT NEXTSTAGE,count(USN) as QTY ,CASE WHEN USN = 0  THEN USN ELSE 0 END FROM sfcfa912.SFCUSN@ro_prd_wmx912 WHERE Line ='R1' and SUBSTR (USN,1,1) = 'R' AND NEXTSTAGE IN 
('AI','AO','H1','IN','WT','TO','TN','PT','SU','WB','QN','TP','BO','CS','WP','WM','RN','RO','IO','IP') 
and trunc (updatetime) >= trunc (sysdate-7)  group by NEXTSTAGE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes crear una tabla derivada *al vuelo* con los valores que te interesa que aparezcan en el conjunto de datos resultante, aunque no haya ningún registro con ese valor en la tabla base.

Una forma simple de crear esta tabla de resultados es una serie de uniones de sentencias del tipo `select 'XX' from dual'`, donde `XX` es cada valor de la lista que actualmente se encuentra en la cláusula `in ()`.

A esta nueva tabla podemos hacerle un `left join` con la consulta que ya te devuelve los resultados.

Un trozo de código es mejor que mil palabras, la idea en SQL es algo como:

```
select v1.Stage, coalesace(r1.QTY, 0)
  from (select 'AI' Stage from dual
        union all select 'AO' from dual 
        union all select 'H1' from dual
        union all select 'IN' from dual
        union all select 'WT' from dual
        union all select 'TO' from dual
        union all select 'TN' from dual
        union all select 'PT' from dual
        union all select 'SU' from dual
        union all select 'WB' from dual
        union all select 'QN' from dual
        union all select 'TP' from dual
        union all select 'BO' from dual
        union all select 'CS' from dual
        union all select 'WP' from dual
        union all select 'WM' from dual
        union all select 'RN' from dual
        union all select 'RO' from dual
        union all select 'IO' from dual
        union all select 'IP'  from dual
       ) v1
       left join 
       (
       SELECT   NEXTSTAGE
              , count(USN) as QTY 
         FROM sfcfa912.SFCUSN@ro_prd_wmx912 
        WHERE Line = 'R1' 
          and SUBSTR (USN,1,1) = 'R' 
          and trunc (updatetime) >= trunc (sysdate-7)  
        group by NEXTSTAGE
       ) r1
       on v1.Stage = r1.NEXTSTAGE
```